# test login with chai

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing

How can i check test that the email is the same that is logged in, and how can i check it's been saved in localstorage?? please help

code:

```
const {expect} = require('chai')
const chai = require('chai')
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http')
const user = require('../src/controllers/user-controller')
chai.use(chaiHttp)

describe('API', () => {
describe('Post /Login', () => {
    it('should login', (done)=>{
        const user = {email:"mikkel.wager@gmail.com",password:"password123"}

      chai
      .request("http://localhost:8200/users")
      .post('/login')
      .send(user)
      .end((err,res)=>{
        expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
        expect(err).to.be.null;
        expect(res.body.email).to.be("mikkel.wager@gmail.com")
        done();
        
      })
    })
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `localStorage.getItem("yourVariableValue")` to get the data you want. But it would only return the data once you have set it in localStorage using `localStorage.setItem("yourVariableValue")`